# Jenkins acs-commons sub package not installing

Tags: jenkins, aem

When I try to build and deploy my aem application package, subpackages (acs commons, core components all) using Jenkins, i am seeing following error in Jenkins console output. Any help ?

```
M Starting installation of subpackage adobe/consulting:acs-aem-commons- 
content:3.15.2

FATAL: org.apache.jackrabbit.vault.packaging.DependencyException: 
Refusing to install package day/cq60/product:cq-content:6.3.76. 
required dependencies missing: 
[adobe/granite:com.adobe.granite.ui.content:0.8.452, 
adobe/granite:com.adobe.granite.ui.legacy:0.1.34, 
adobe/granite:com.adobe.granite.ui.shared.content:1.1.18, 
adobe/granite:com.adobe.granite.platform.content:0.5.52, 
adobe/granite:com.adobe.granite.platform.welcome:1.1.12, 
adobe/granite:com.adobe.granite.platform.clientlibs:1.1.106, 
adobe/granite:com.adobe.granite.security.content:0.2.174, 
adobe/granite:com.adobe.granite.replication.content:1.0.30, 
adobe/granite:com.adobe.granite.monitoring.content:1.0.26, 
adobe/granite:com.adobe.granite.backup.content:0.0.62, 
adobe/granite:com.adobe.granite.cluster.content:0.0.40, 
adobe/granite:com.adobe.granite.activitystreams.content:0.0.22, 
adobe/granite:com.adobe.granite.workflow.content:1.0.48]

Build step 'Deploy Content Packages to CRX' changed build result to 
FAILURE
```

Comment: Looking at the required dependencies, it says some of AEM's library packages are missing. Check if the AEM instance has been installed properly in the first place and do a quick health check of the instance - if all the bundles are active, no console errors, basic admin pages are opening up, etc

Comment: wat version of aem are you using and wat acs commons version? From logs, you are using 3.15.2 which works AEM 6.2 and above only.

Comment: Yes, i am using AEM 6.3.2 (sp2)

Comment: Does the error happen when you build locally? Any differences between local and author instances, that is, Service Packages, hotfixes?

Comment: Issue does not happen locally(mvn command build). It happens when build triggered through jenkins.